# Laravel Carbon Invalid Datetime Format Error during DST

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-5.3, dst, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 5.3 and I insert `datetime` in mysql columns where the value is generated from the Controller using Carbon.

I have a lot of errors during a particular time in my error logs like this:

```
Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-10-01 02:29:54' for column 'invite_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `wedding_invitations` (`name`, `email`, `invite_at`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Donald Trump, trump@donald.com, 2017-10-01 02:29:54, 2017-08-02 02:29:54, 2017-08-02 02:29:54)) in /home/myapp/applications/weddingapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:770
```

I see that the issue is not the date format since `2017-10-01 02:29:54` is a valid sql format. After digging into it and reading the other answers here in SO, I found that my server time is set to `AEST` and I think the error happened since the time between Oct 1 2am - 2.59.59am doesn't exist due to Day light savings. That is probably why I am getting this error.

The `invite_at` date is created in my controller like this:

```
$invitationDate = Carbon::now()->addDays(60);
```

My question is:

1. How can I fix the above issue?  Since I don't want it to enter an invalid date due to the DST? I don't want to be changing the timezone in mysql or server just to resolve this issue.
2. Another idea I was thinking was, when the `addDays` is called, maybe set the time to `23.59.59` since that could avoid this error. For me the date is important than the time. So if I want `addDays` in `Carbon` to set a fixed time, how can I do that?

Comment: so you can add `->endOfDay()` to the `addDays()` function?

Comment: Perfect!!! Shortly after I posted it, I was thinking of `setTime(0,0)`, but `->endOfDay()` seems perfect to what I am after. Thank you. I will try that now.

Comment: Brilliant, it works and exactly what I wanted. Thank you. If you can post it as an answer, I am happy to accept it and mark this resolved. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the comment I made as answer for whatever reason:

Because the you are concerned about date than time you can set the date_time value you get from Carbon to `startOfDay()` or rather as stated in my comment to `endOfDay()` i.e:

```
$invitationDate = Carbon::now()->addDays(60)->endOfDay();
```

One other method is simply use date as your column type for `invited_by`, then you can avoid the issue with the time (since you said the date is more important).